# MongoDB: aggregate and $near

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

This is my `drivers` collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e9efd94c02272f4029b5c6"),
    "driverId" : 386,
    "firstname" : "John",
    "middlename" : null,
    "lastname" : "Doe",
    "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    36.29102901,
                    -1.29012381
            ]
    },
    "driverState" : "available",
    "contacts" : {
            "email" : "email@email.com",
            "phoneNumber" : "07000000",
            "imei" : "",
            "gcmCode" : ""
    },
    "vehicle" : {
            "vehicleId" : 0,
            "registration" : null,
            "capacity" : 4,
            "vehicleClass" : "GOLD",
            "model" : null,
            "colour" : null
    },
    "cabCompany" : {
            "cabCompanyId" : 8,
            "name" : "princeton cabs"
    }
}
```

I want to fetch the nearest driver to a geo-point grouped by `vehicle.vehicleClass` and `vehicle.capacity`.

So if I have `GOLD,SILVER` as the possible values for `vehicle.vehicleClass` and `4,7` as the possible values for `vehicle.capacity`, then the query should return a maximum of four documents:

`GOLD,4`, `GOLD,7`, `SILVER,4` and `SILVER,7` where each of the results is the nearest to the geo-point supplied.

And possible how is that translated to spring-data with mongo

This is what I had tried but I got the error: $near is not allowed inside a match

```
db.drivers.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        loc: {
            $near: {
                $geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [36.2901920192, 
                    -1.29102939202]
                },
                $maxDistance: 100000
            }
     }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "vehicle.vehicleClass": "$vehicle.vehicleClass", "vehicle.capacity":"$vehicle.capacity"
        }
    }
}
])
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: where are you failing ? what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I have added my attempted query.

Comment: You may want to check on $geoNear aggregation. Not sure if $near can be used with aggregation. You can do everything with $geoNear that you do with $near.